# How to write an OR statement with evaluations on either side

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following code:

```
def custom_validation
    errors[:base] << "You must enter two street names" if self.streetone.blank? || self.streettwo.blank?
    errors[:base] << "You must enter a valid 5-digit zipcode" if self.zipcode.blank? || ( self.zipcode.count != 5 )
end
```

The second statement on `zipcode` is throwing an error: `wrong number of arguments (0 for 1+)` but I'm not sure how to improve it.

Comment: can you post the error log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`count`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-count) on string does not do what you think it does:

> **count([other_str]+) → fixnum**
>
> Each other_str parameter defines a set of characters to count. The
>   intersection of these sets defines the characters to count in str. Any
>   other_str that starts with a caret ^ is negated. The sequence c1-c2
>   means all characters between c1 and c2. The backslash character
>   `</code>` can be used to escape `<code>^` or - and is otherwise ignored
>   unless it appears at the end of a sequence or the end of a other_str.

use [`length`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-length) instead

```
errors[:base] << "You must enter a valid 5-digit zipcode" if self.zipcode.blank? || 
 ( self.zipcode.length!= 5 )
```

Comment: Yup this worked. Oh interesting, so it was the method that was incorrect, not the way I wrote the statement... I did think that was weird...